# Not able to insert data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried this code where I want a user to fill a form to raise ticket & on click of submitting the data must be inserted in the DB. I have written the query for it but not able to get the form data into it.

**Form.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Raise Ticket</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("form#form-submission").submit(function(){ /* WHEN THE FORM IS SUBMITTED */

                var formData = {
                    'ename'    : $('input[name=ename]').val(),
                    'date'     : $('input[name=date]').val(),
                    'ext'  : $('input[name=ext]').val(),
                    'issue'    : $('select[name=issue]').val(),
                    'query'     : $('input[name=query]').val()

                };

                $.ajax({ /* CALL AJAX */
                    url: "insertticket.php", /* THE FILE WHERE THE DATA WILL GO */
                    type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO BE USED TO PROCESS THE DATA */
                    data: formData, /* THE DATA TO BE PROCESSED */
                    contentType: false, /* TYPE OF DATA TO BE PASSED; FOR FILE PURPOSES THAT IS WHY IT IS SET TO FALSE */
                    processData: false, /* PREVENT AUTOMATIC PROCESSING */
                    success: function(result){ /* IF DATA IS PROCESSED SUCCESSFULLY */
                        alert('Ticket Raised Successfully ' ); /* ALERT THE RETURNED DATA FROM inserticket.php */
                    }
                });

                return false;

            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h1 align="center">Helpdesk</h1></div>
            <hr>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li><a href="HomePage.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="NetworkIssue.php">Network Issue</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Software Issue <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="SoftwareIssue.php">Software</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ERP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CRM</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="HardwareIssue.php">Hardware Issue</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Ticket.php">Raise Ticket</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <div class="panel-body" align="center">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form-submission">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="text" name="ename" value="<?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['usr_name']);  ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Date:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control" disabled id="date" name="date" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta"); echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="ext">Extension No.:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input  type="number" class="form-control" id="ext" name="ext" placeholder="Enter Extension No.">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="issue">Issue Type:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select required="true" class="form-control" id="validate-issue" name="issue">
                                    <option>Select an option</option>
                                    <option>Hardware Issue</option>
                                    <option>Network Issue</option>
                                    <option>Software Issue</option>
                                    <option>ERP</option>
                                    <option>CRM</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="query">Query:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <textarea required="true" rows="5" class="form-control" id="validate-query" name="query" placeholder=" Enter Query here"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="panel-footer" align="center">&copy Copyright <?php echo date("Y");?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**insertticket.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "root"; // Mysql username
$password = ""; // Mysql password
$db_name = "help"; // Database name

// Connect to server and select database.
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect");

mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);

$sname = $_SESSION['usr_name'];

$sqli  =  "select * from user where name = '$sname'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $emp_code = $row['emp_code'];
    $dept = $row['department'];
    $location = $row['location'];
    $emailid = $row['emailid'];
    $contact_no = $row['contact_no'];
}

$emp_name  =  $_SESSION['usr_name'];
$date  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
$issue_type  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['issue']);
$query  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['query']);
$ext_no  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ext']);
//$attachment  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FLIES['upload']['name']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO ticket (emp_code,emp_name,dept,location,emailid,contact_no,date,issue_type,query,ext_no)
VALUES('$emp_code','$emp_name','$dept','$location','$emailid','$contact_no','$date','$issue_type','$query','$ext_no')";
if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
    echo "Record added";
}
else
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What is the status in firebug (Net tab). Post is working or not? Check insert.php or insertticket.php is loading or not.

Comment: I am not able to get the form values into the db. I am able to fetch the values in the while loop. Its d same file Sir.

Comment: try to add some dummy data by using insert.php. If it is working fine then you can focus on ajax part.

Comment: if `ticket_no` is autoincrement then no need to write it in insert query

Comment: Ok I will remove ticket_no. from the query as its auto increment.

Comment: check what do you get in result after ajax call

Comment: I am not expert in ajax-jquery trying for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to use mysqli or pdo. mysql is deprecated. It is no longer updated.

Check in firebug under net tab. Your data is getting submit or not. If not then you can focus on **form.php**.

Try to put below code in test file and run the file in your browser.

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="help"; // Database name 
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);

$emp_code ='1';
$emp_name = 'test data';
$dept = 'test data';
$location ='test data';
$emailid = 'test data';
$contact_no = 'test data';
$date = '01/10/2016';
$isuse_type ='test data';
$query = 'test data';
$ext_no ='test data';

$sql="INSERT INTO ticket (emp_code,emp_name,dept,location,emailid,contact_no,date,issue_type,query,ext_no)
VALUES('$emp_code','$emp_name','$dept','$location','$emailid','$contact_no','$date','$issue_type','$query','$ext_no')";
if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
echo "Record added";

  }
else
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
 }
```

Let us know it is adding data in sql or not. This will help us to check `insertticket.php` after that we can focus on ajax.

Comment: good. What browser you are using? if you have firefox then add firebug and then press F12. You need to check network tab. We are not sure data is getting submitted by ajax or not.

Comment: i am using Google Chrome Sir!

Comment: Try to install firefox. it will help you in future development as well. Also try to echo session data. Are you getting session data or not. echo $sname=$_SESSION['usr_name'];

Comment: Ok. So this is working so i feel my form page has some problem ? As i am not able to get the values of fom into the db

Comment: You have two queries in insertticket.php one is select and another one is insert. Insert is working fine but you need to check select query is returning data or not.

Comment: Wid the dummy data i was able to get values of select query & then the dummy data i added to the form values

Comment: Are you getting data from session or not. Try to print/echo session data. You insert query is dependent on select query and select query is using session data. So, check session variable is returning data or not.

Comment: Yes my session data is working & the query based on the session data is working fine

Comment: Now you need to check form.php. It seems like problem with Ajax.

Comment: Yes. I have used var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); & used NOW() in insert query & got the desired result